# Submitted Assignment Late - Wrong to ask for in-depth analysis?

Tags: time-management, lecturer

So I've just submitted my first late assignment, and another one on the books. I feel absolutely terrible about it, but my time-management has been less than poor lately.

I really enjoy learning though, and if there is one thing that drives me, it's to aim for the highest result possible. As such, when I submit my assignments, I usually prod for further analysis as to where I was lacking, what I can improve, etc.

However, typing an email to my lecturer currently feels 'wrong'. I feel, because the assignment was late, that I put in a half-assed effort, and feel like asking for a more in-depth analysis is like asking for 'more' than I deserve. Should I surmise this 'idea' in my head to my lecturer when asking for the analysis of my assignment? Or should I just go about it the way I did before, just asking for ways to improve, etc.?

Comment: @Ian_Fin Is there anything about the question that could not apply to a graduate student?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Probably not. I've deleted the comment. It may be worth the OP's while if a little more context was provided though, e.g., are there extenuating circumstances, how late was the assignment, etc.

Comment: You submitted late and did half-baked job. It does happen. However, why would you expect the lecturer to invest on a piece of work that you yourself consider subpar? Any information that they could give you would probably concentrate on the things you anyway know are problematic in this submission. If you did your best job, detailed feedback from the lecturer is valuable. But if you didn't, and you know it anyway, you are just wasting their time (or rather take their time/attention from students who did - in this particular instance - a better attempt).

Comment: @Ian_Fin The only circumstances that led to this late submission were poor time management on my half; I don't actively seek 'excuses' so to speak as to why I couldn't submit on time. The lateness wasn't anything horrendous - simply 2 business days after due date. The penalty is 10% of the overall mark. I hope that answers your queries, Ian.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Well put, exactly what I was trying to determine - and get input from someone with a better perspective to see this from a 3rd party perspective of those who may know better than myself. I would mark this as an answer, if you would kindly post it as such.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 As per request, converted into response, with some minor edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You submitted late and did half-baked job. It does happen to the best of us.

It does not, however, make sense to expect the lecturer to invest on a piece of work that you yourself consider subpar. Any information that they could give you would probably concentrate on the things you anyway know are problematic in this submission. If you did your best job, detailed feedback from the lecturer is valuable in refining your work.

But if you didn't, and you know it anyway, you would just utilize their time/attention to little effect and would take it away from students who did - in this particular instance - a better attempt.